# ES6 equivalent to SQL cross join

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Is there a way in JS to take these two arrays, `scenarios` and `items`, and essentially cross join them to end up with the output shown in `result`?

```
const scenarios = ['a/2020-12-01', 'b/2020-12-04'];
const items = ['201/17', '201/28', '207/3', '208/4', '208/12'];

const result = [
    'a/2020-12-01/201/17', 'a/2020-12-01/201/28', 'a/2020-12-01/207/3', 'a/2020-12-01/208/4', 'a/2020-12-01/208/12',
    'b/2020-12-04/201/17', 'b/2020-12-04/201/28', 'b/2020-12-04/207/3', 'b/2020-12-04/208/4', 'b/2020-12-04/208/12'
];
```

I have had no success searching online for how to do this - possibly because I don't know the correct name for what this is in JS terminology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Array.flatMap()` to iterate the `scenarios` and flatten the results, with `Array.map()` to iterate the items, and combine them with the scenarios:

```js
const scenarios = ['a/2020-12-01', 'b/2020-12-04'];
const items = ['201/17', '201/28', '207/3', '208/4', '208/12'];

const res = scenarios.flatMap(scen =>
  items.map(item => `${scen}/${item}`)
);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with [`.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as follows:

```js
const scenarios = ['a/2020-12-01', 'b/2020-12-04'];
const items = ['201/17', '201/28', '207/3', '208/4', '208/12'];

const res = scenarios.reduce((acc,scen) => {
  acc.push(
    ...items.map(item => `${scen}/${item}`)
  );
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(res);
```

Another simple solution using two `for-loops`:

```js
const scenarios = ['a/2020-12-01', 'b/2020-12-04'];
const items = ['201/17', '201/28', '207/3', '208/4', '208/12'];

const res = [];

for(let i = 0; i < scenarios.length; i++)
  for(let j = 0; j < items.length; j++)
    res.push(`${scenarios[i]}/${items[j]}`);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I agree. Seems to be a common trend to use fancy shorthand ES6 few liners, which one has to transform back to ES5 or backtrack to comprehend.